# Given a series of dimensions/factors, how can I create a dataset with a determinate number of rows?

Tags: r

I have a series of dimensions and I'd like to make datasets of fixed numbers of rows for testing.

Here's a minimal example:

```
Example dimensions
sex <- c("M", "F")
age <- 18:65
nationality <- c("AU", "AT", "ES", "FR", "MX", "IN")
eye_colour <- c("blue", "brown", "green", "hazel")
```

What I need is a function that takes these and outputs a data.frame with all columns, no duplicates and a fixed number of rows.

Example output:

```
> randomise_data(10, sex, age, nationality, eye_colour)
```

```
   sex age nationality eye_colour
1    M  37          AT      brown
2    F  37          AT      brown
3    M  52          AT      brown
4    F  52          AT      brown
5    M  37          FR      brown
6    F  37          FR      brown
7    M  52          FR      brown
8    F  52          FR      brown
9    M  37          AT      green
10   F  37          AT      green
```

For reference, the code I used to make the above dataset was:

```
vars <- list(
sex = c("M", "F"),
age = 18:65,
nationality = c("AU", "AT", "ES", "FR", "MX", "IN"),
eye_colour = c("blue", "brown", "green", "hazel")
)

sample_data <- lapply(vars, sample, 2)

expand.grid(sample_data)[1:10,]
```

But I don't want to have to manually choose a number each time and it obviously wouldn't work with 3 instead of 2. **The combination of all factors in the real case is too large for me to just calculate that and subset it to the desired number of rows**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer that doesn't create a huge grid:

```r
set.seed(123)
vars <- list(
  sex = c("M", "F"),
  age = 18:65,
  nationality = c("AU", "AT", "ES", "FR", "MX", "IN"),
  eye_colour = c("blue", "brown", "green", "hazel")
)

desired_length = 10

# get the number of levels in each variable
var_lengths = vapply(vars, length, 1L)

# Find combination of variables that work using solver. Use sum of squares as penalty for difference between desired number of rows and the number of rows given by solver.
solution <- optim(par = sqrt(var_lengths), 
                  fn = \(x) (desired_n - Reduce("*", x))^2,
                  method = "L-BFGS-B",
                  lower = 1,
                  upper = var_lengths)

# Round up values given by solver
sub_vars <- mapply(\(x,y) sample(x,y), vars, ceiling(solution$par))

# Get all combinations given by solver (not all combinations of original levels)
max_grid <- expand.grid(sub_vars)
# Subset to desired number of rows
result <- max_grid[sample(nrow(max_grid), desired_length),]
result
```

```
   sex age nationality eye_colour
5    M  59          FR      brown
27   M  60          FR      green
28   F  60          FR      green
9    M  54          FR      brown
29   M  54          FR      green
35   M  59          AU      green
8    F  60          FR      brown
26   F  59          FR      green
7    M  60          FR      brown
10   F  54          FR      brown
```

Answer (score 2):

A generalized procedure using brute force. Ugly but allows for full automation of the process.

```r
set.seed(1234)
num_rows <- 10
vars <- list(
  sex = c("M", "F"),
  age = 18:65,
  nationality = c("AU", "AT", "ES", "FR", "MX", "IN"),
  eye_colour = c("blue", "brown", "green", "hazel")
)
all_combinations <- combn(unlist(vars), length(names(vars))) |> t()
idx <- lapply(1:length(names(vars)), function(x) {
  nm <- names(vars)[ x ]
  which(all_combinations[ , x ] %in% vars[[ nm ]])
})
idx <- Reduce(intersect, idx)
idx <- sample(idx, num_rows)
sample_data_df <- all_combinations[ idx, ]
sample_data_df <- data.frame(sample_data_df)
colnames(sample_data_df) <- names(vars)
sample_data_df
```

```
   sex age nationality eye_colour
1    M  59          MX      hazel
2    M  43          IN      green
3    M  56          IN      brown
4    M  34          FR      hazel
5    F  59          ES      brown
6    F  37          MX      brown
7    M  63          IN      green
8    M  29          AT      brown
9    F  62          IN      hazel
10   F  55          ES      hazel
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `replicate`. With a sufficiently large number of factors, there is a very small chance of getting duplicates, or otherwise you can oversample and remove duplicates:

```r
as.data.frame(t(replicate(10, sapply(vars, sample, 1))))

#    sex age nationality eye_colour
# 1    F  43          AU      green
# 2    M  56          IN      hazel
# 3    M  39          AT       blue
# 4    M  34          AT      hazel
# 5    F  29          MX      brown
# 6    F  38          AU      brown
# 7    F  34          ES       blue
# 8    M  41          AU       blue
# 9    M  23          AT      hazel
# 10   M  29          IN      brown
```

---

You can use `expand.grid`, as you do, to get all possible combinations, and `sample` 10 of those:

```r
expand.grid(vars)[sample(prod(lengths(vars)), 10), ]

#      sex age nationality eye_colour
# 1788   F  47          AU      hazel
# 544    F  49          IN       blue
# 598    F  28          AU      brown
# 137    M  38          AT       blue
# 1111   M  45          IN      brown
# 1142   F  60          IN      brown
# 1148   F  63          IN      brown
# 169    M  54          AT       blue
# 28     F  31          AU       blue
# 257    M  50          ES       blue
```

Comment: The problem is the `expand.grid(vars)`. It works in the dummy example, but the real case has hundreds of values so it becomes too large a table.

Comment: I think a more efficient version of the second on would be `as.data.frame(sapply(vars, sample, n, replace = TRUE))` and it works well, but would start failing as n approaches half the size of the dataset.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative approach using a custom function that takes the number of rows and the list of dimensions as arguments and generates a random dataset with the specified number of rows:

```
randomise_data <- function(n, ...) {
  vars <- list(...)
  df <- expand.grid(vars)
  df <- df[sample(nrow(df), n), ]
  return(df)
}

sex <- c("M", "F")
age <- 18:65
nationality <- c("AU", "AT", "ES", "FR", "MX", "IN")
eye_colour <- c("blue", "brown", "green", "hazel")

randomise_data(10, sex, age, nationality, eye_colour)
```

```
     Var1 Var2 Var3  Var4
1983    M   49   ES hazel
6       F   20   AU  blue
172     F   55   AT  blue
1439    M   65   ES green
50      F   42   AU  blue
1272    F   29   AT green
1357    M   24   ES green
929     M   50   FR brown
365     M   56   FR  blue
993     M   34   MX brown
```

Comment: The problem is that `expand.grid`. The solution needs to avoid making giant tables as combinations can expand quickly